# Default operator AND is not working for multi-field query_string in elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch, search, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I am searching for text "The British government on Monday" but not getting result.
my query is given below.

```
GET _all/_search
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "The British government on Monday",
              "default_operator": "AND", 
              "fields": [
                "title",
                "description",
                "full_description",
                "link",
                "content"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

my doc field contains
"full_description": "BIRMINGHAM, England -- The British government on Monday dropped plans to cut income tax for top earners, part of a package of unfunded cuts unveiled only days ago that sparked turmoil on financial markets and sent the pound to record lows.
kindly help me in this.

Comment: I created a doc with just the "full_description" field, without any analyzer. I ran your query and got the document.
I think it would be good to provide an example document and the mapping, as you may be using some analyzer that we don't know about.

Comment: Sharing a sample document and index details such analyzer would help replicate the exact scenario.